# Adding a zero to a decimal

Tags: python

for a string:

```
0.1 --> 0.10
0.2 --> 0.20
0.3 --> 0.30
0.35 --> 0.35
```

Example:

```
print(str(round(variableB.count('X') /len(variableA), 2)))
```

I tried `print("%.2f" %str(round(variableB.count('X')/len(variableA),2)))`, but I got `TypeError: must be real number, not str`

then I tried

```
print ("%.2f" % int(str(round(variableB.count('X') /len(variableA), 2))))
```

but I got `TypeError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.47'`

same result with `"%02d" %`

Comment: `"%.2f" % round(variableB.count('X') / len(variableA), 2)`…!? The `str()` and `int(str())` is simply superfluous.

Comment: Trailing zeros on a floating point number do not accomplish anything.

Comment: @user99999.  if you are trying to show significant digits to demonstrate precision of the value, they have a purpose

Comment: It was for display purpose and thank you, it worked.

Comment: @user99999 The entire context of this question was within print statements, so it is obviously both being displayed, and does not need to be explicitly converted a str data type.

Answer (score 3):

An f-string (added in Python 3.6) is *a* perfectly valid way to accomplish this.

```
>>> num = 3.1
>>> f"{num:.2f}"
'3.10'
```

Using `%`:

```
>>> "%.2f" % num
'3.10'
```

Both specify two digits of precision when displaying a floating point number.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `%` for string interpolation. This will work in more Python versions than using f-strings. For example:

```
def printZero(num):
    print("%.2f" % num)


printZero(0.1)  # => 0.10
printZero(0.2)  # => 0.20
printZero(0.3)  # => 0.30
printZero(0.35)  # => 0.35
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 0.1
b = 0.2

#old formatting
print("%.2f"%a) # output 0.10

# f-strings in 3.5+
print(f"{b:.2f}") # output 0.20
```